# Do glass bottles weaken over time?

Tags: equipment, bottles

I bottle to flip top 750 ml bottles.  Should I keep using the same ones forever, or do they weaken over time, and I should get a new set some day?

I'm not extremely careful with them, I often clean them in my stainless steel sink, stack them...  I primarily do beer, but also carbonated hard lemonade and cider.

And please, for the love of science, don't even think of telling me that glass is a liquid.  The two forum posts I clicked on when I started researching this had people saying that glass at normal temperature is a liquid.

Comment: Everyone knows glass is a vapor at room temp, and solid in the fridge.  Sheesh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll be ok to use them for a good few years to come.  Glass is quite a tough substance...

To be honest i'd be more worried about the cap - the rubber seals on those will perish at a much faster rate than the glass will.  Once you start seeing the rubber get dry, and/or start to crack then i'd start to think about replacing.

You might even be able to get replacement seals for the caps.

Comment: plus 1. It's the gaskets that are the weakest link. The glass will last for a long time. Yes, it is a liquid, but incredibly viscous at room temperature. If you look at some very old windows, you can see a small amount of "dripping down" of the glass. But for a beer bottle, just forget that it's a liquid. It will probably outlast you.

Comment: @mdma I warned you for the love of science to not spread that myth.  Old windows are thick at one end because they were manufactured with the crown glass process http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_glass_(window).  They put the thicker end at the bottom because it's simply more stable that way, but I would bet that you can find old windows installed upside down that are thick on the top

Comment: ok, I didn't read your post as considering that to be a myth, and didn't see any warning.  I was told this when I was a kid, and it's stuck with me. But regardless, which state of matter it assumes is not really relevant, the bottles will be fine.

Comment: @mdma think nothing of it.  we are in the same boat